# How to replace when using GNU find's -printf predicate?

Tags: find

My find command:

```
find * -type d -printf '%p\n'
```

And this is the result:

```
Icons
Index
Index/Team
Index/Pricing
Index/WhyUs
Navbar
Share
```

I want to get to this result:

```
Icons   components/Icons/Exports
Index   components/Index/Exports
IndexTeam   components/Index/Team/Exports
IndexPricing    components/Index/Pricing/Exports
IndexWhyUs  components/Index/WhyUs/Exports
Navbar  components/Navbar/Exports
Share   components/Share/Exports
```

I can change my find command to this:

```
find * -type d -printf '%p\tcomponents/%p/Exports\n'
```

But I get this result:

```
Icons   components/Icons/Exports
Index   components/Index/Exports
Index/Team  components/Index/Team/Exports
Index/Pricing   components/Index/Pricing/Exports
Index/WhyUs components/Index/WhyUs/Exports
Navbar  components/Navbar/Exports
Share   components/Share/Exports
```

How can I replace slashes in the first `%p`?

Answer (score 2):

`-printf` (a predicate specific to the GNU implementation of `find`) has no provision for doing any modification on the different `%x` directives, except for the string padding/truncating ones with `%5p` / `%-5p` / `%.5p`...

But here, you don't need `find`. With the `zsh` shell:

```
for f (**/*(N/)) printf '%s\tcomponents/%s/Exports\n' ${f:gs|/||} $f
```

Which also has the benefits of giving you a sorted list and excluding hidden directories.

You can do the same with `find` if you post-process the output with GNU `sort` and something like `gawk` for instance:

```
find . ! -name . -type d -print0 |
  sort -z |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='\0' '
    {
      name = path = substr($0, 3)
      gsub("/", "", name)
      print name"\tcomponents/"path"/Exports"
    }'
```

Or to exclude hidden ones like in `zsh`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . '(' -name '.*' -prune -o -type d -print0 ')' |
  sort -z |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='\0' '
    {
      name = path = substr($0, 3)
      gsub("/", "", name)
      print name"\tcomponents/"path"/Exports"
    }'
```

Also beware that in `find *`, it's the shell that expands `*` first to the list of files in the current directory and passes them to `find`. That means that:

- hidden files in the current directory are excluded (but not in subdirectories as it's `find` that finds those).
- if any of the file names start with `-` or are find predicates, that will confuse `find`
- the top level list will be sorted (as shells sort their glob expansions by default), but not the sublevels (as `find` doesn't)
- if there are many non-hidden files in the current directory, you may run into a *arg list too long* error when trying to execute `find` with too big a list.

If we replace `find *` with `find .`, then it's `find` that looks for files in there and all the problems above are avoided. That also means that `.` (the starting point) will be in the list so we need to exclude it with `! -name .` or `-mindepth 1` (GNU extension), and a `./` prefix will be shown on output which we strip here with `substr($0, 3)` though we could also use GNU `find`'s `-printf '%P\0'` instead of `-print0` instead.